# Change Background Color with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, drop-down-menu

I have a form with multiple drop downs... I would like to set the background color of the visible dropdowns to gray when they are disabled. All of these dropdown's id's begin with usrControl. Here is what I have this far..

```
    $('select[id ^= "usrControl"]:visible').each(function(){
this.css("background-color")
});
```

Not sure how to get the disabled/enabled selectors.

Thanks in advance
[image]

```
Protected _picklistColorScriptText As String = "$(document).ready(function(){ " + _
                                                "$('[id ^= ""usrControl""]:visible:disabled').css(""background-color"", '#DCDCDC'); " + _
                                                "$('[id ^= ""usrControl""]:visible:enabled').css(""background-color"", '#FFFFFF');" + _
                                                "});"
```

This works. However, this sets the background for the entire control to gray, how can I change the color of the selected item to gray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the :disabled pseudo-selector. Plus you don't need jQuery.each. Just work against the returned nodeset.

```
$('select[id ^= "usrControl"]:visible:disabled').css("background-color", 'gray');
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cwm4W/

UPDATE: Responding to OP's clarification below, you can simply select the contained option like so:

```
$('select[id ^= "usrControl"]:visible:disabled option').css("background-color", 'gray');
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cwm4W/1/

Comment: This works. However, this sets the background for the entire control to gray, how can I change the color of the selected item to gray?

Comment: You can just select the option tag beneath the select. See updated answer above.

Comment: Man, you guys are good!! Thanks!! One last question. How can I do the same for an input (textbox) not the entire control, just the textbox I want to change the color the gray.

Comment: To change a text input, $('input:text').css('background-color', 'gray'). This will set the entire textbox to gray. (You don't have much choice as <input type='text'> doesn't have any child elements. If you want a different effect, you'll have to modify other CSS properties. BTW - You can also comma-separate your selection list and then apply the css to all selected elements. e.g. $('A, B, C').css(...).

Comment: I've been injecting this jQuery code from the code behind of a .net user control... It has occurred to me that this application of jQuery could have been accomplished using AJAX... I'm still doing a postback... I'm curious as to how I might be able to get this code to execute whenever there is a change on the page and not have to inject?

Comment: This is a completely separate question. Please post it as such so that others can find it and provide their thoughts too. BTW - If you want people to continue to answer your questions, you should mark accepted answers as such.

Comment: Opened a new question for this item. Thanks for your help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503485/fire-jquery-script-when-postback-occurs

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting the CSS property.
Try this:

```
$(this).css( "property", "value" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for

```
$('select[id ^="usrControl":visible:disabled].each(...
```