# Fire jQuery script when postback occurs

Tags: jquery

I've been injecting this jQuery code from the code behind of a .net user control... It has occurred to me that this application of jQuery could have been accomplished using AJAX... I'm still doing a postback... I'm curious as to how I might be able to get this code to execute whenever there is a change on the page and not have to inject?

```
Protected _picklistColorScriptText As String = "$(document).ready(function(){ " + _
                                                "$('[id ^= ""usrControl""]:visible:disabled').css(""background-color"", '#DCDCDC'); " + _
                                                "$('[id ^= ""usrControl""]:visible:enabled').css(""background-color"", '#FFFFFF');" + _
                                                "});"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the JS/jQuery code in the pageLoad function instead of (document).ready in the html instead of in the code behind. pageLoad will fire on all postbacks.

```
function pageLoad(){

    jQuery here...

}
```

Comment: Will this occur even on partial page postbacks? I am using Ajax update panels.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to register that script in the code-behind... if you place it in your html, it will execute each time your page loads (posts back)

Comment: Will this occur even on partial page postbacks? I am using Ajax update panels.

Comment: documentReady will not fire on  partial postbacks

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to run that code in $(document).ready() and ajaxComplete().

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

```
function styleControls() {
    // your styling code
}

$(document).ready(styleControls)
           .ajaxComplete(styleControls);
```

Comment: Thanks James, although Stephens method works, I will try yours as well, since you have a habbit of giving out such good coding advice!!!

Comment: first i have heard of this method. I will give it a try as well.

Comment: I haven't tried pageLoad(), but it would be specific to Microsoft's implementation of UpdatePanels. jQuery.ready()/ajaxComplete() works if your AJAX calls are being done via jQuery.